# A7672E AT-commands for GPS and bluetooth problem

Tags: iot, gsm, lte

I have A7672E module (+CGMR: A011B13A7672M7). It's bluetooth and gps command not working. What should I do? Can you help me? Thanks.

A7672E-LASE
INCORPORATED
A011B13A7672M7.

I need A7672E-FASE version